# Erro no arquvio POM.XML do maven

Tags: java, maven, pom

***Erro***

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'dependency'. One of '{"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":parent, "http://maven.apache.org/
>    POM/4.0.0":name, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":description, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":url, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":prerequisites, 
>    "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":issueManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":ciManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":inceptionYear, 
>    "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":mailingLists, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":developers, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":contributors, "http://
>    maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":licenses, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":scm, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":organization, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/
>    4.0.0":build, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":profiles, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":modules, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":repositories, "http://
>    maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":pluginRepositories, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":dependencies, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":reports, "http://
>    maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":reporting, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":dependencyManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/
>    4.0.0":distributionManagement, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":properties}' is expected.

***POM.XML***

```
<code>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.wdn.curso</groupId>
    <artifactId>intro-spring-mvc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <build>
        <finalName>intro-spring-mvc</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>9090</port>
                    <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
</code>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As dependências informadas no seu [POM](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html) devem estar contidas dentro da tag `<dependencies>`.

Conforme exemplo que consta na [documentação](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: mesmo depois de adicionado a tag `<dependencies>` o erro continua o mesmo.

Comment: Não sei qual IDE está utilizando, mais no Eclipse, precisa atualizar o Projeto Maven (`ALT + F5`).

Comment: Estava usando o eclipse, e agora que atualizei o projeto maven funcionou! Valeu pela ajuda.